# How do I remove a kernel package from an image chroot if it's the kernel running on my build host?

Tags: centos7, yum, linux-kernel, chroot

I am trying to build a custom image using `diskimage-builder`, and amongst other things, that tool updates all the packages within the image to the latest version, including the kernel.  It also uses `package-cleanup` to remove any old kernels.

However, `package-cleanup` has logic to prevent you uninstalling the current kernel; this makes sense on a regular host, but when you are operating inside a chroot to build a filesystem, it doesn't.

Temporarily patching `package-cleanup` to disable this logic reveals that `yum` has the same logic, and I believe `rpm` does too!

Relevant distro/package info:

- Host: CentOS 7 (built from Minimal-1810, with some updates)

  - diskimage-builder-2.16.0-1
  - yum-utils-1.1.31-50
  - kernel-3.10.0-957.12.2
- Image: CentOS 7 (GenericCloud-1905)

  - kernel-3.10.0-957.12.2 (from source image)
  - kernel-3.10.0-957.27.2 (added by diskimage-builder)

Now, obviously, if I update the build host to the latest kernel, this problem goes away... but only until the kernel version on the host and in the source image are the same again and a more recent kernel is released that `diskimage-builder` then adds.

To complicate this further, when `diskimage-builder` installs the newer kernel, `grubby` is run to build the relevant grub configuration, but this fails for related reasons; it pays attention to the currently running kernel, even though that's irrelevant.  This means that not only is an old kernel left on the new image, but it remains the default.  And as it happens, 3.10.0-957.12.2 doesn't boot on one of my target systems (VMware), which is why this is such a problem for me.

Is there a better solution here?  Can I force `package-cleanup`, `yum`, or `rpm` to remove the older kernel package somehow?  (Ideally `package-cleanup`, as it already contains the logic to dynamically work out which kernels to keep/remove.)

(Tools that try and protect you from doing the wrong thing really should allow you to override them when you know what you're doing.  Also, package management tools shouldn't refer to the currently running environment, as that may not be the eventual target.)